# Sourcing free live traffic layers to use in MXD of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, arcgis-9.3, mxd, data

I am looking for free live traffic layers for an ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 MXD.

My searches haven't been that successful.

Comment: You can't get live-feed information in the form of an ArcMap layer. ESRI online gets their feed from Here.com.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to provide more information about what such a "live traffic layer" would look like, please?  Also, including the searches you have done and what in their results did not match your requirements will help narrow down what you are looking for.